# jQuery: trying to use serializeArray()

Tags: jquery

I have the code below. I expected it shows the in JSON format the values and the name of the fields, but just show this:

> [object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


                $('#forma').submit(function() {

                    alert($(this).serializeArray());
                    return false;
                 });

});    

</script>


<form id="forma">
  <div><input type="text" name="a" value="1" id="a" /></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="b" value="2" id="b" /></div>
  <div><input type="hidden" name="c" value="3" id="c" /></div>
  <div>
    <textarea name="d" rows="8" cols="40">4</textarea>
  </div>
  <div><select name="e">
    <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select></div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="f" value="8" id="f" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit" id="g" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Regards

Javi

Comment: What are you trying to get from this?  A pretty print version of the data or something usable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) returns an array of objects like this:

```
[{name: "name", value: "value"}....]
```

To get a string you can see, use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) like this:

```
alert($(this).serialize());
```

This is the same as calling [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) on the array, like this:

```
alert($.param($(this).serializeArray()));
```

To be clear, this is a format for a data string, e.g. a GET or a POST, you should use `JSON.stringify()` yourself if you want to serialize it to JSON.

Answer (score -1):

For those who want a more hands-on code:
    `fData=$("#myForm").serializeArray(); // or $("#myDiv :input").serializeArray();
    //alert(fData.length) // how many inputs got picked up
    var msg="";
    for(var i=0;i<fData.length;i++){
        var raKy=Object.keys(fData[i]);
        msg+="\n"+raKy[0]+":"+eval("fData[i]."+raKy[0])+" "+raKy[1]+":"+eval("fData[i]."+raKy[1]);
    }
    alert(msg);`

You can limit scope to a div within a form by using the commented out code instead